# How to start rmic registry and server using java 1.7?

Tags: rmi, java-7

I am new to java RMI, actually I wrote, compiled and started rmic, and also tried to start server but failed due to _stub 'ClassNotFound' exception..... I'm using java 7... I searched a lot on Google but nobody told step by step example that could work...I got some idea about stteing codebase and security policy but not very clear suggestion that how to do it.. please help telling me steps including command-line .......... please... I have everything just tell me how to start server, and required settings like codebase or policy settings etc... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `rmic`. Instead, create your server object and call one of the `exportObject()` method overloads that has the port parameter. For example,

```
MyRemoteIntf stub = UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(server, 0);
```

This will cause RMI to generate the stub automatically. (The documentation is horribly unclear on this point. If you use the version without the port parameter, it will use only the old, `rmic`-generated stubs instead of generating them automatically.)

Also, make sure that your remote interface is in the codebase of both the registry and any clients. You'll get different errors if you haven't done this properly. This has been answered a bunch of times on Stackoverflow already; search for "rmi ClassNotFoundException".

Comment: The ['horribly unclear' documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/rmi/server/UnicastRemoteObject.html) says this: "If the remote object is exported using the UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(Remote) method, a stub class (typically pregenerated from the remote object's class using the rmic tool) is loaded".

Comment: You're correct that the behavior **is** documented. But compare the docs for [`exportObject(Remote)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/rmi/server/UnicastRemoteObject.html#exportObject%28java.rmi.Remote%29) and [`exportObject(Remote,int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/rmi/server/UnicastRemoteObject.html#exportObject%28java.rmi.Remote,%20int%29). There is no mention of the difference in the treatment of stubs. It's quite counterintuitive that the addition of the `port` parameter, pertaining to networking, radically changes the treatment of stubs.

Comment: One of these days I'd like to fix this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

There is no need to use the `rmic` command since java (J2SE) 5.0 the stubs are dynamically generated at runtime.

## Here is a basic step by step example of how to use RMI.

First define the Remote interface that defines what the client can see and do:

```
public interface FooService extends Remote {
    // Don't forget to add throws RemoteException.
    public void bar() throws RemoteException;
}
```

**NOTE:** if you do not add `throws RemoteException` to the method declaration you will encounter the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: illegal remote method encountered: public abstract void RMIExample.FooService.bar()
```

After you defined what the client can do you must define the concrete implementation of the methods on the server slide:

```
public class FooServiceImpl extends UnicastRemoteObject implements FooService {
    public FooServiceImpl() throws RemoteException {
        super();
    }

    public void bar() {
        System.out.println("I was remotely invoked!");
    }
}
```

The implementation class must inherit from `UnicastRemoteObject` and implement the Remote interface you defined earlier and the class must have a constructor that throws RemoteException.

Now that you have fully defined the remote functionality you must bind the implementation object to a URL on the server side:

```
// 4000 is the port to listen on.
LocateRegistry.createRegistry(4000);
Naming.rebind("//127.0.0.1:4000/foobar", new FooServiceImpl());
```

Now that you have your server up and running you need a stub instance A.K.A a proxy in the client side:

```
FooService fooService = 
       (FooService)Naming.lookup("//127.0.0.1:4000/foobar");
```

and finally invoke the remote method:

```
fooService.bar();
```

the following should be printed on the server side:

```
I was remotely invoked!
```

**References:**

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_remote_method_invocation
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/rmi/relnotes.html

Comment: The implementation class does not have to extend UnicastRemoteObject, but if it does it must call super() with a port number, otherwise dynamic proxies cannot be generated. Naming.rebind("//0.0.0.0...,) not only does not mean 'accept connections from anywhere', it doesn't work at all. -1 for non-working example.

Comment: @EJP if you don't subclass UnicastRemoteObject and implement java.io.Serializable in FooServiceImpl you will result in a server that is up and running but instead of the Naming.lookup() returning a stub it will return a serialised instance of FooServceImpl which means instead of the method being invoked on the remote server it is invoked on the clients machine, the documentation of UnicastRemoteObject says "Used for exporting a remote object with JRMP and obtaining a stub ...", plus calling super() uses the port of the registry, plus i run this example before posting it, and it works for me.

Comment: I didn't say a single word about implementing `Serializable.` If you don't subclass `UnicastRemoteObject`, all you have to do is call `UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject()` to export the object as a remote object. That's what the method is for. This is all in the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/rmi/server/UnicastRemoteObject.html) and in the [RMI Specification #5.3.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/rmi/spec/rmi-server24.html).

Comment: And calling `super()` or `exportObject()` without a port number (1) prevents a dynamic stub being generated, and (2) doesn't 'use the port of the registry' unless you have created the Registry with `LocateRegistry.createRegistry()`. What it really does is use a system-allocated port, or reuse an existing system-allocated port if you have already exported a remote object (e.g. the Registry).

Comment: And you have neither addressed nor fixed your error about `0.0.0.0` in `Naming.rebind()`. Nor, apparently, ever tested this code. It does not work. Would you care to explain that.

Comment: @EJP You are right the URL in the rebind method is not a network address it is the path to the location of  the registry, and I apologise for the mistake, but like i said before I built an example project, ran it and it worked for me.

Comment: Your IDE must have magical properties. Anybody else would have got a `java.rmi.ConnectException` in `Naming.rebind()` because of the `0.0.0.0`. And you aren't 'bind[ing] the object to a URL', you are binding to the Registry with a name. And you still haven't fixed your mistake about 'must extend `UnicastRemoteObject`'.